# Undefined index error in php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="test.php">
<label for="contact">Mobile No:</label><br>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="contact" title="Mobile number should not contain alphabets. Maxlength 10" placeholder="Enter your phone no" maxlength="15" required  id='contact_no'>
      <br><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id='reset'>Reset</button>
  </form>

Ajax and Javascript Code
script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
        var dialcode = $(".country-list .active").data().dialCode;
        var contact = $("#contact_no").val().replace(" ","");
        var countrycode = $('.country-list .active').data().countryCode;
            var cn;
            var cc;
            var dc;
            $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'cc' : contact},
            success: function(data) 
            {
                alert("success"); 
              }  
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The variables show the values if displayed by alert message but are not passed on to the test.php page. It shows undefined index error at the following statement

**test.php** is as follows

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

         $contact = $_POST['cc'];       //it shows the error here

    }
    echo  $contact;
```

I had referred to many websites which show the same thing. It dosent work for me. I think the syntz of ajax is correct and have tried all possibilities but still dosent work. Please help

Comment: ^this, you don't need quotes around your keys in a javascript array

Comment: Remember to set the dataType in the $.ajax request.

Comment: You're posting `{cc: contact}`, but you're checking for `$_POST['submit']` which isn't being sent. The callback also doesn't stop the event, so you might want to `return false` (stops default and propagation)

Comment: `@Naitik` can you please try the codes, and mark anyone as answer which gives you correct result that you want and that will be descriptive also. you can vote-up others if they are helpful too. thanks. we diid code for you. at-least check them.

Answer (score 2):

You're posting `{cc: contact}`, but you're checking for `$_POST['submit']` which isn't being sent. The callback also doesn't stop the event, so you might want to `return false` (stops default and propagation). Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function()
{
    //do stuff
    $.ajax({
        data: {cc: contact},
        method: 'post',
        success: function()
        {
            //handle response here
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Then, in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['cc']))
{
    //ajax request with cc data
}
```

Also not that this:

```
$("#contact_no").val().replace(" ","");
```

Will only replace 1 space, not all of them, for that you'll need to use a regex with a `g` (for global) flag:

```
$("#contact_no").val().replace(/\s+/g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ajax` to `form submit`

and you use `$_POST['submit']` to check it would be `$_POST['cc']`

**test.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['cc'])){// change submit to cc
      $contact = $_POST['cc'];//it shows the error here
    }
echo  $contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Saty answer worked for me, but my code on ajax was a bit different. I had multiple form data wrapped up into a form variable, that was passed to the php page.

```
const form = new FormData();

form.append('keywords', keywords);
form.append('timescale', timescale);
form.append('pricing_entered', pricing_entered);

 $.ajax({
   url: "../config/save_status.php",
   data: form,
   method: "POST",
   datatype: "text",

success: function (response, data) {

                   }
```

Then my php was:

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
 // all code about database uploading
}
```